# Table rows not working in Firefox, Chrome, Safari

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, cross-browser

I have a big chunk of CSS and HTML in a SharePoint 2010 page (inserted directly via SharePoint Designer, not within a webpart). I put all my HTML inside of a div to keep it from messing up SharePoint's markup.

I have a table of links with background images that change on hover. It looks fine in IE11 (2 columns x 2 rows) but in Firefox, Chrome and Safari it's borked (1 column x 4 rows). Here's my janky markup (forgive me, not sure what's relevant):

CSS

```
#MV td {
height: 90px;
width: 300px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}
#MV td a {
display: block; 
padding: 1.5em 0em 0em 0em;
height: 75%;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
}
#MV td a:hover {
background-image: url('img2.gif');
background-position:top left;
}
.sensory {
display:block;
background:transparent url('img.gif') center top no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="MV">
<!--sensory table-->
<table style="float:left;">
<caption>Sensory and<br/>Product Development</caption>
<tr>
<td class="sensory"><a href="#">Sensory Discrimination<br/>Panel Test</a></td>
<td class="sensory"><a href="#">Sensory<br/>Cutting</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="sensory"><a href="#">Sensory Sample<br/>Screening</a></td>
<td class="sensory"><a href="#">Organoleptics<br/>Evaluation</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

How can I force my table to 2x2 for all four browsers? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

Remove **Display : Block** from **.sensory**

```
    .sensory {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:transparent url('img.gif') center top no-repeat;
      }

    #MV td a {
     display: block;
     padding-left: 5px;
     width: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: This works beautifully in Firefox and IE. In Chrome and Safari, though, the text of the link and the hover image are now displaced downwards, instead of being centered vertically in the cell.

Comment: Remove height and padding from #MV td a ...... add verical-alighn to sensory ....I've modified my ans...